# LNK2011: Why does LINK.EXE require stub.obj to be linked alongside precompiled header?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, linker-errors, nmake

My question arises after reading this very tiny explanation on MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ay26wa2.aspx

For the record, it seems like a "precompiled object" is just the .obj file that was used in the creation of a .pch (precompiled header) file.

According to MSDN, you need to link the precompiled object together with all the other .obj files that use it's corresponding .pch file. Why? If the other .obj files are compiled with CL.EXE using the /Yu option, then they literally contain the .pch right? After all, the precompiled object in most cases is just a bunch of pre-processor directives...

Comment: No, the point of PCH is that each translation unit (== object file) *doesn't* need to recompile the common headers. They are compiled once and placed into a PCH file, not into each OBJ file.

Comment: So why do I need to link an empty object file containing nothing but #include "headertobecompiled.h"? I ended up fixing my link error this way, but I can't understand why it was a necessary step.

Comment: You'll have to ask Microsoft to get an accurate answer.  But clearly your assumptions are wrong, a header file does not just contain preprocessor directives.  It is perfectly valid to have a definition in a header file, it is common for inlined functions for example.  Most troublesome with the question is that, if somebody posts a documented reliable answer, you are not going to do anything else.

Comment: It's not the precompiled header that contains just pre-processor directives, it's the precompiled object. It seems that Microsoft calls the .obj responsible in the creation of a precompiled header a precompiled object. For instance, in the link above, a .c file consisting of nothing but a #include "headertobecompiled" MUST be linked in order to avoid this link error. For what reason though, I can't imagine. Since in my case, the "precompiled object" contained absolutely nothing but a single pre-processor directive, and the generated precompiled header were "used" (/Yu) in the other .c files.

Comment: To clarify, the precompiled object and the precompiled header both coexist in the same directory (in this case) after creating the precompiled header from the precompiled object.

Answer (score 0):

A pch is very far from being a bunch of preprocessor directives. It is much closer to a cache of front-end compilation on all types included (directly or indirectly) in the translation unit.  Typical inclusion of standard headers, say `<windows.h>` or `<vector>`, amounts eventually to hundreds of files and sometimes hundreds of thousands of lines of code, so caching their processing is substantial.

If for example you'd compile a type with one `#pragma pack` into a pch and with a different `pack` (or `align`) into other translation units - you'd have an insidious bug on your hand, as these translation units won't agree on the object layout.

The whole point of a pch is to avoid having other object files generate and include this information. And after it is generated *once* it *must* be linked with all obj files missing it.